# Verify naming of C# event trigger functions

Tags: c#, events, publish-subscribe

I am new to C# and I found this documentation and example about events in C#:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines

For me especially these lines are of interest:

```
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Write some code that does something useful here
        // then raise the event. You can also raise an event
        // before you execute a block of code.
        OnRaiseCustomEvent(new CustomEventArgs("Event triggered"));
    }

    // Wrap event invocations inside a protected virtual method
    // to allow derived classes to override the event invocation behavior
    protected virtual void OnRaiseCustomEvent(CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        // Make a temporary copy of the event to avoid possibility of
        // a race condition if the last subscriber unsubscribes
        // immediately after the null check and before the event is raised.
        EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> raiseEvent = RaiseCustomEvent;

        // Event will be null if there are no subscribers
        if (raiseEvent != null)
        {
            // Format the string to send inside the CustomEventArgs parameter
            e.Message += $" at {DateTime.Now}";

            // Call to raise the event.
            raiseEvent(this, e);
        }
    }
```

For me this naming does not make sense at all or I did not understand how the events work in C#. If I am not wrong then in DoSomething the CustomEvent is triggered. But normally onAnything functions are listening on events. Do you also think that OnRaiseCustomEvent should be named RaiseCustomEvent?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is the c# naming convention.
You don't have to agree with it, but you should be familiar with it and I would also recommend using it in your code.

An experienced c# programmer that will see a method called `On<blabla>` that take in an argument named `EventArgs` or anything that ends with the suffix `EventArgs` (like `<blabla>EventArgs`) will immediately expect this method to raise an event called `<blabla>`.
(Naturally, `<blabla>` is just a placeholder for an actual name)

This pattern exists because while events are being inherited, the only way to raise them is within the declaring type - as documented in [How to raise base class events in derived classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-raise-base-class-events-in-derived-classes):

> ... events are a special type of delegate that can only be invoked from within the class that declared them. Derived classes cannot directly invoke events that are declared within the base class.

This is why you need the `On<blabla>(BlaBlaEventArgs e)` method to be `protected virtual` (unless your class is declared as `sealed`) - so that it's derived classes will be able to raise the `<blabla>` event as well.

Official documentation also admits that (at least some of) the names chosen in this pattern are somewhat misleading - [as mentioned here:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines)

> The name EventHandler can lead to a bit of confusion as it doesn't actually handle the event.

Personally, I think they might have chosen better names for this as well as for the `On<blabla>` methods, but it's way, way too late to change it now.